# How I can ONLY get the first level folders (main folders) inside document library, seems "Get-PnPFolder -List $Library" retrieve all the sub-folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have this script to loop through all site collections >> and all document libraries  >> then list the folders in this format "Site Name >> List Name >> Folder Name":

```
$AdminUrl = "https://*****-admin.sharepoint.com/"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminUrl -Interactive 
 
#sharepoint online get all site collections PowerShell
$SiteColl = Get-PnPTenantSite
 
 
#sharepoint online PowerShell iterate through all site collections
ForEach($Site in $SiteColl)
{
 
   Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Site.Url -Interactive
   $Webs = Get-PnPSubWeb -Recurse -IncludeRootWeb
               
               
    #Get All document libraries
ForEach($Web in $Webs)
    {
               $DocumentLibraries = Get-PnPList -Web $Web | Where-Object {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Title -ne "Site Assets" -and $_.Hidden -eq $false}
    #Iterate through each document library
    ForEach($Library in $DocumentLibraries)
               {
               $f =   Get-PnPFolder -List $Library
               
               ForEach($folder in $f)
               {
               
               Write-Host $Site.Title " --> "  $Library.Title  " --> " $folder.Name
               }
               
               }
}
 
 
}
```

but the issue I am facing is that `Get-PnPFolder -List $Library` will get all the main folders and sub-folders. So how can I restrict this command to only get the main folders (first level folders) without sub-folders?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to get only the top-level folders using `Get-PnPFolder` command.

As per the [source code](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/blob/e06c687263f07f3d2908970a2cac42ece6f71d46/src/Commands/Files/GetFolder.cs), `Get-PnPFolder` uses `CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery()` to retrieve the folders inside the provided list/library.

And `CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery()` creates a query that can be used to recursively get all of the folders in a list/library.

**Source**: [SP.CamlQuery.createAllFoldersQuery() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff407697(v=office.14))

Comment: so any other approaches to only get the main folders other than using PnP?

Comment: Not sure if possible using PnP PowerShell

Comment: i mean other than pnp is there a way>

Comment: Check if this helps: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1da7db11-4d06-458f-b926-3d169ed66f8e/powershellget-list-of-first-level-folder-in-a-document-library?forum=sharepointdevelopment